# Update record query in Parquet file system using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I want to update apache parquet data using apache spark. I having daily new records what i had to do is to read current records in spark and then do some aggregations on new and old records and after that i update those records in parquet file system.

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First store initial records into hive table like below.

**sparkSession.read.parquet("parquetFilePath").write.saveAsTable("someHiveTable")**

Create data frame with new records

**val newData:Dataset[Row]= // data frame with new records**

Use any of the below approach to append records

**a) newData.insertInto("someHiveTable")**

**b) newData.write.option("mode","append").saveAsTable("someHiveTable")**.

Comment: Will it update or append my current parquet file? Or its like we do in cassandra when we append it matches primary key and overwrite those records that are already present.